# What is wrong with (a >=0) % 5 as it gives me 1 instead of 0

Tags: python-3.x

Doing a simple if elif program and I used `(a>=0) % 5` were a is just an input however it doesn't work and always works out to equal 1. New to programming not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What logic are you trying to implement? Only check %5 if a is greater than 5?

Comment: you will find that when `a` is negative you will get an output of 0, since that makes the condition `False` which gets converted to 0 when you do `%5`.

Comment: how would I go about fixing it, because a=int(input()) in which I want a >=0. Is it possible to add these two parts together so I can just write a % 5 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `a >= 0` evaluates to `True` if `a` is indeed superior or equal to `0`.

`True` and `False` are subclasses of `int`, so `True % 5` evaluates to `1 % 5` which gives `1`.

Try with a negative `a`, and you will see that `(a >= 0) % 5` will give you `0`.

Examples:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> (a >= 0) % 5 
1
>>> a = 0
>>> (a >= 0) % 5 
1
>>> a = -3
>>> (a >= 0) % 5 
0
```

If you wish to always have a positive `a` in `input`, you can do the following:

```py
a = -1
while a < 0:
    # ask for the input while a is stricly negative
    a = int(input())

print(a)
```

Comment: how would I go about fixing it, because a=int(input()) in which I want a >=0. Is it possible to add these two together so I can just write a % 5 instead?

Comment: If you wish to always have a positive `a` inside the `input`, the result of `(a >= 0) % 5 ` will always be 1. Your computation of `(a >= 0) % 5` would become useless in this case ^^

Comment: I mean is there a way to add the range >=0 to my input so instead of (a >= 0) % 5 I can then just write it like a % 5 which would fix it.

Comment: Mb I wasn't giving you enough details but the input must be greater than or equal to 0 which would then lead into an if elif structure using a % 5 == 0 ....  a % 5 ==1 .... and so forth

Comment: Nevermind lol it works great I just didn't get it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Considering the following expression:

```
 (5 >= 0) % 5
```

The comparison `(5 >= 0)` is evaluated as `True`, which is then converted to `1`.
Therefore you see the result of:

```
1 % 5
# 1
```

Comment: how would I go about fixing it, because a=int(input()) in which I want a >=0. Is it possible to add these two together so I can just write a % 5 instead?

Comment: So you would like to allow non-negative inputs only, then do a % 5 on the input number?

Comment: yes, the input must be any number greater than or equal to 0 which would then allow me do to input(a) % 5

Comment: Gotcha. vinzee's answer, specifically the second part with the while loop would be a good solution for that.